# How can I check for empty command line arguments at different positions in PYTHON?

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to detect if the 2nd command line argument is an empty string "".

The full command line argument will consist the following: (Method, Username, Password)

```
python Hello.py AddUser Mark 123321
```

I am suppose to give to give an ERROR if the username is an empty string. I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
    if sys.argv[1] == "AddUser":
        if sys.argv[2] == "":
            print("Error: username missing")
        else:
            AddUser(sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])
```

But I am getting the following Error:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\hello>python Hello.py AddUser  123123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hello.py", line 148, in <module>
    main()
  File "Hello.py", line 11, in main
    AddUser(sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I resolve this issue ? Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: This isn't a Python question, rather a basic shell operation question, but what the heck. You are only specifying two arguments: `AddUser` and `123123`. The second one isn't blank so it tries to add the user, but there's no third argument, so it fails trying to get it. To specify an empty argument, quote the argument: `python Hello.py AddUser "" 123123`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now I understand it better, and yes you're right about "" mentioned in the command line, I thought it was just space.